# replace with value from array Python

Tags: python, python-2.7

I create txt file with my name in 3 lines of strings :

```
adam1
adam2
adam3
```

and  array

```
array = ['Tom','Monica','Jean']
```

I wanna to replace "adam1" with "Tom" from array and "adam2" with "Monica" etc .

```
import string
s = open("test.txt",'r')
array = ["Tom''Monica','Jean']
```

I start code but i dont know how create for loop to do this with replace() method. Can anybody help?

Comment: Please show an example of the input and output. Question is not clear.

Comment: *I wanna to first line in txt replace with 0 index of names* - how that? Try again with explanation

Comment: @kowal666, you chose not correct answer for your task

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
with open('test.txt') as fin:
    lst = list(map(lambda s: s.strip(), fin))

with open('test.txt', 'w') as fout:
    lst[:len(array)] = array
    for elem in lst:
        fout.write(str(elem) + '\n')
```

Answer (score -1):

```
with open('test_input.txt') as fin, open('test_output.txt','w') as fout:
    for num, line in enumerate(fin,0):
        fout.write(replace_array[num]+'\n')
```